# Replacing a string in Rubymine with a string with newlines

Tags: rubymine

I want to use the Search and Replace dialogue in Rubymine, or something similar to replace something like "Scenario:" with "@Desktop\nScenario"

I'm trying to replace every instance of `Scenario:` in a large Cucumber test suite with

```
@desktop 
Scenario:
```

Any best ways to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update:**

Thanks to [@ryan2johnson9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3097602/ryan2johnson) comment, I realise there's now an easier option (tested on 2017.3).

By clicking on the "New Line" (or using the shortcut Ctrl+Shift+Enter / Alt+Enter), the input becomes multilines.

[image: New line]
[image: Multiline]

---

**Original Answer**

In the search and replace box, if you tick the "Regex" option you can do:

Search: "Scenario:"
Replace by: "@desktop\nScenario:"

The only trick is to tick the "Regex" option :)

Comment: A bit late, but I'd still like to note for anyone seeing this that you need to escape any regex special characters -- so if you have a `[]` or `{}` in your search string, it has to get backslash-escaped.

Comment: In Rubymine 6.3 I was able to click the multiline button just right of the search input. Now I have Rubymine 8.0.3 and that feature does not seem to be there anymore :(

Comment: @ryan2johnson9: when you are in the search input do "alt+enter" and it will switch to a multiline input

Comment: thanks @ouranos I think alt+enter is an easier option then regex.

Answer (score 0):

Rubymine has macros (http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/binding-macros-with-keyboard-shortcuts.html) but I dont think they are powerful enough for this example.

It's possible that you could solve it with some elaborate feature hidden inside Rubymine, but I think it would be a lot easier to do this with a tool like perl/sed from the Terminal. If you are using Windows I assume you could search the net and find a text search/replace tool that fits your need.

In OSX I there are a bunch of Text Substitutions app too.

I would go that route since Rubymines macro tool isnt up to the task.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cheap and sleazy alternative:

1. Copy a newline character from between two empty lines in the file being edited.  Temporarily add two empty lines if you don't have any.
2. Set up search/replace and enter the string you want to replace into the **search** text input box.
3. Paste the newline you just copied into the **replacement** text box plus whatever other text you want.  You will be able to see the height of the replacement text input box grow vertically by one line due to the newline.
4. Perform the search/replace.

For this, the use of the Rubymine **regex** is optional.